# Question about implicit class argument in Java method reference

Tags: java, functional-programming, implicit

In Java, the class portion of a method reference can become the first argument of the function. I've seen lots of examples in working code. But I wondered where in the Java Language Specification this is spelled out? I'm wondering because whenever I see code like this, it takes me a few minutes to figure out why there is an "extra" first argument. So I thought it would be helpful to read the actual rule. It does not seem to be mentioned in the sections on functional interfaces or method references.

Here is an example.

```
import java.util.function.BiFunction;

public class TestBiFunction
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BiFunction<A.B, Integer, Integer> fx = A.B::dbl;
        A.B b = new A.B();
        int result = fx.apply(b, 3);
        System.out.println("Result = " + result);
    }

    private static class A {
        private static class B {
            public int dbl(int x) {
                return 2 * x;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, specifically what I wondered was, in the statement "BiFunction<A.B, Integer> fx = A.B::dbl;", what language rule makes the "A.B" in "A.B::dbl" become the first argument to the BiFunction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pain to find in the Java Language Specification, but I think you're looking for [section 15.13.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.3), at least in version 8 of the spec, specifically the line

> If the compile-time declaration is an instance method, then the target reference is the first formal parameter of the invocation method. Otherwise, there is no target reference.

Comment: Thanks. That sounds like what I was looking for.So if an instance method of some class is referenced, e.g. TargetClass.someMethod(int arg1, String arg2), then the functional interface should have a method like "apply(TargetClass inst, int arg1, String arg2), and invoking fxn.apply(inst, 3, "a") will invoke inst.someMethod(3, "a").

Answer (score 0):

As @LouisWasserman 's answer mentions, it's §15.13.3

One useful way to think about:

```
receiver.method(arg1, arg2);
```

Is that there is no meaningful difference between that and:

```
TypeOfReceiver.method(receiver, arg1, arg2);
```

*Other than* dynamic dispatch (where at compile time the expressions' type is relevant, but at runtime, the actual object you find by following the reference, and if that is of a more specific type that has overridden the method, the overridden implementation is called - this is unique to instance methods, and not something static methods get).

In fact, at the JVM level it actually works that way, more or less, and you can even actually add it to a method definition! This is legal java:

```
public class MyExample {
  void instanceMethod(MyExample this, int param1) {
  }
}
```

The `instanceMethod` is an instance method with 1 (!) parameter (param1). You invoke with: `new MyExample().instanceMethod(5)`. The `MyExample this` is completely ignored, but legal. It exists so you can put annotations on the 'receiver'.

When thinking about this hypothetical instance method, it really does have 2 parameters. The JVM implementation will push 2 things on the stack before invoking it: The `this` reference, and the `param1` value.

The same thinking applies for lambdas. Given **just** "Hey, I'm talking about the instanceMethod as a method", then it really does have 2 parameters.

Java does allow partly bound concepts, though - you can choose to provide half of the parameterlist (specifically, the `this` ref):

```
MyExample myEx = new MyExample();
IntConsumer ic = myEx::instanceMethod;
ic.accept(5);
```

That works - that final line is identical to calling `myEx.instanceMethod(5)`. The `myEx` reference is 'baked in' to `ic`, so that's where that comes from, and the '5' is provided by calling `accept`.

In contrast:

```
MyExample myEx = new MyExample();
BiConsumer<MyExample, Integer> tif = MyExample::instanceMethod;
tif.accept(myEx, 5);
```

(There is no BiIntConsumer primitive variant so we have to resort to autoboxing to make this one work) - here our `tif` function has neither parameter pre-bound, so *both* would need to be provided. After all, it is not possible to invoke `instanceMethod` without, well, an instance of `MyExample`. So how would `tif.accept(5)` work - what is `this` going to be within the context of the `instanceMethod` code?

Thus, my advice is - aside from reading the spec specifically about lambas, consider instead that **every non-static method in java** has, as first parameter, `TypeThisIsIn this`, even if you don't write it. You *can* write that if you want, the compiler will let you, even.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed explanation. It really rounds out the rather terse explanation in the JLS. Your comment about partially binding the reference is especially helpful because in the code I've dealt with, we happen to have had examples of that much more often than fully unbound method references, so they tended to obscure the fully unbound case slightly.